# What is the correct one Whose , Who or Which

Tags: which-who, whose

Q)Fill in each gap with an appropriate word from the list :

-The writer ....... novels were translated into many languages won the Nobel Prize.

Choices :

a)whose 
b)who  
c)which

Comment: What do you think it is? And why?

Answer (score 2):

"whose" as it shows possesiveness.